# Reading certificate hash from remote server

Tags: c#, .net, windows, iis-7.5, wsastartup

I receive an error when trying to get a certificate hash from a remote machine using the following code:

```
private string getCertHash(string Hostname)
{
    string result = "";

    using (ServerManager serverManager = ServerManager.OpenRemote(Hostname))
    {
        SiteCollection siteCollection = serverManager.Sites;
        foreach (Site site in siteCollection)
        {
            foreach (Binding binding in site.Bindings)
            {
                if (binding.Protocol == "https")
                {
                    // Error here
                    foreach (Byte certhashbyte in binding.CertificateHash)
                        result += certhashbyte.ToString(); 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

The error I receive in more detail:

> 'binding.certhashbyte' threw an exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'
>
> Either the application has not called WSAStartup, or WSAStartup
>   failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007276D)

If I replace the following row:

```
using (ServerManager serverManager = ServerManager.OpenRemote(Hostname))
```

with

```
using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager)
```

to use the local server it works fine.

Note that using ServerManager.OpenRemote(Hostname) works in general (I get all the other information, just the CertHash info results in an error. I have admin rights on both machines (local and remote). System is Windows 2008 R2 using IIS 7.5.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong / what is missing / why the error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason the code above now works fine. I couldn't find out why it did not work, but I did find some alternatives I want to share:

1. Using [this code](http://hamidshahid.blogspot.com/2009/02/reading-x509-certificates-from-remote.html) and here an example usage:

   ```
   CertStoreReader certStoreReader = new CertStoreReader();
   foreach (X509Certificate2 x509 in certStoreReader.GetCertificates(credentials.Hostname))
   {
       certHash = x509.GetCertHashString();
   }
   ```
2. Using the ServerManager as first tried above (in the question)

   ```
   using (ServerManager serverManager = ServerManager.OpenRemote(server))
   {
       Site site = serverManager.Sites.Where(s => s.Name == websiteName).Single();
       foreach (Binding binding in site.Bindings)
       {
           certHash += BitConverter.ToString(binding.CertificateHash).Replace("-", string.Empty);      
       }              
   }
   ```
3. Using DirectoryEntry

   ```
   DirectoryEntry dir = new DirectoryEntry(@"IIS://" + server + @"/W3SVC/" + siteID);
   PropertyValueCollection vals = dir.Properties["SSLCertHash"];
   foreach (string entry in vals)
   {
       certHash += entry;
   }
   ```
4. Using WMI. I used this query in the WebAdministration namespace:

   ```
   "SELECT CertificateHash FROM SSLBinding WHERE IPAddress = '" + IP + "' AND Port = " + port
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just simply do:

```
using (var store = new X509Store(@"\\[RemoteMachineName]\My", StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
{
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    certificates = store.Certificates;
}
```

Just make sure you have the right permission to access the remote machine certificate store.